# Dropdown in AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, autocompletetextview

My AutoCompleteTextView is working fine. I am using the AutoCompleteTextView to add data to the database. However, I fail to see the recently added data getting displayed in the dropdown list of the AutoCompleteTextView. Every time I need to restart the activity to display the data that was recently added to the database. Are there ways to display the very recently added data without restarting the activity?

Update:

```
    String[] autoCompleteSupplierName = vivzHelper.getSupplierName();
    ArrayAdapter<String> supplierNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, autoCompleteSupplierName);
    supplierName.setThreshold(1);// starts working from first char
    supplierName.setAdapter(supplierNameAdapter);
```

Comment: Could you please add your code...

Comment: you are working with sqlite, right? so dont use ArrayAdapter but rather [Simple]CursorAdapter